# How to rewind page stack in tab when re-selecting tab in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs, ionic2

I have an Ionic-2-App with tabs. In Tab 1, one can navigate to subpages. Now, when I select another tab and then re-select the first tab, I would like to rewind the pages inside this tab to see the root page of the first tab again.

On the tab-component, on my first tab, I can add `(ionSelect)` to call a method inside the tab.ts.

**tab.html:**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"
             (ionSelect)="rewind()"
             tabIcon="icon1"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"
             tabIcon="icon2"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"
             tabIcon="icon3"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tab.ts:**

```
// [...]

export class Tabs {

    tab1Root:any = MyFirstRootPage;
    tab2Root:any = MySecondRootPage;
    tab3Root:any = MyThirdRootPage;

    constructor( private nav:NavController ) {}

    rewind():void {
        // How can I rewind the pages in tab 1 here?
        // Probably, I should do something like "nav.pop()", 
        // but how?
        console.log( 'Tab 1 selected' );
    }
}
```

How can I rewind the pages in tab 1 without breaking the navigation inside this tab?

**Update**

tab.ts:

```
import { Page, NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HousiPage } from '../housi-page/housi-page';
import { DocalizrPage } from "../docalizr/docalizr";
import { InfectionListPage } from '../infection-list/infection-list';
import { StandardListPage } from '../standard-list/standard-list';

@Page( {
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
} )
export class TabsPage {
    // Die Präventions- und die More-Seite sind beides
    // StandardListPages, aber mit unterschiedlichen
    // Parametern
    preventionPageParams:any = {
        slug: 'prevention',
        hasThumbnails: true,
        pages: []
    };
    morePageParams:any = {
        slug: 'more',
        hasThumbnails: false,
        pages: []
    };


    // this tells the tabs component which Pages
    // should be each tab's root Page
    tab1Root:any = DocalizrPage;
    tab2Root:any = HousiPage;
    tab3Root:any = InfectionListPage;
    tab4Root:any = StandardListPage;
    tab5Root:any = StandardListPage;

    constructor( private nav:NavController, public app:App ) {}

    rewind():void {
        this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot( DocalizrPage );
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Subscriber.js:229 Uncaught 
ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in build/pages/tabs/tabs.html:2:4", _originalException: TypeError: this.app.getActiveNav(...).setRoot is not a function at TabsPage.rewind (http://local…, _originalStack: "TypeError: this.app.getActiveNav(...).setRoot is n…//localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:94488:18)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in build/pages/tabs/tabs.html:2:4↵   …//localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:94496:30)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject `app: App` from "ionic-angular",

and then call `this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(RecipesPage);`

in your code `this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(MyFirstRootPage);`

look at this example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ShoppingListPage} from "../shopping-list/shopping-list";
import {RecipesPage} from "../recipes/recipes";
import {App} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  shoppingList: any = ShoppingListPage;
  recipes: any = RecipesPage;

  constructor(public app: App) {

  }

  rewind() {
    console.log('Clicked Recipe Tab');
    this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(RecipesPage);
    //const root = this.app.getRootNav (); // in this line, you have to declare a root, which is the app's root
    //root.popToRoot (); // here you go to the root.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I get an error: `this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(xyz) is not a function`.

Comment: Edited my question